# How can I put shipping and billing address on one page in virtuemart ?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am trying to customize by putting shipping and billing address in registration page (group them by putting rectangle box) and have a check box for billing if it is same as shipping address. The problem is, I have no idea how to do it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, but I don't mean the default code, but the piece of code of what you've tried to achieve the result you want. We're not here to code all you want, we're here to help you with pieces of code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Registration fields could be set under:

```
Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Shopper Fields
```

There are options if you want to show / hide fields in: Registration form, Shipment form, Account maintenance.

In order to group them with a rectangle box you have to set the appropriate `delimiter` fields for each section and design them with css.

Hope this helps